# What is the workflow to implement pre-traind tensorflow neural network from python to c++ using tensor-rt?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorrt

As the title said, i'm trying to use a pre trained tensorflow network implemnted in python in a c++ code using Nvidia's tensor-rt library. I understood that I need to create an .pb file from "freeze graph" (I have no idea what that mean) and than use it in c++ with tensor-rt API somehow.
Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

there is a guide on how to do so [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/tensorrt-integration-speeds-tensorflow-inference/), its made by the guys at Nvidia, also if you install tensorrt you will have the sample code on TF deployment in this direction:

```
/usr/src/tensorrt/samples/sampleUffMNIST
```

And as always check on the TensorRT documentation https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html

That should get you started! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use [TF-TRT](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt), here is the documentation for it: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/integrate-tf-trt/index.html

There are also examples here that can help you to start: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt